# How to create an application that can be minimized to Windows XP taskbar?

Tags: c#, windows

I want to create an application that user can minimize to taskbar on Windows XP.

Like

1. [**iTunes**](http://www.online-tech-tips.com/computer-tips/how-to-minimize-itunes-to-the-windows-taskbar/)

   [image]
2. Windows Media Player
3. Google search

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You are looking to create an [Application Desktop Toolbar](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc144177%28VS.85%29.aspx) A simple example on doing so in C# with a Band Object is available here:

http://www.codeproject.com/KB/shell/dotnetbandobjects.aspx

Answer (score 1):

It is known as [DESK BAND](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa969320.aspx)